# two dimensional apply by in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `map` function to map to two separate arrays. Basically in `for` loop syntax,

```
for exp in expiration:
   for symb in symbol:
         f(exp,symb)
```

I currently have in my code:

```
map(expiration, lambda exp: map(symbol, f(exp,symbol) )
```

But the error I'm getting is that the 2nd argument of `map()` must support iteration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the arguments to `map` backwards, it should be a function then an iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've gotten the arguments wrong, the iterable is supposed to come *after* the lambda:

```
map(lambda exp: map(symbol, f(exp,symbol), expiration)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a nested list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
result = [ f(exp, symb) for exp in expiration for symb in symbol ]
```

I think this is easier to read and understand.

However, if you don't need the result from the list comprehension, I would just use your original approach, as you are creating a list unnecessarily.

Comment: I know that the above works as well but I didn't want to waste memory by creating a list unnecessarily. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: `map` would create lists as well, so I think you should just use your original approach.

Comment: `map` returns an iterator in Python 3, but neither would it call `f` until you iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in map function. First argument is function, second is an iterable.

```
map(lambda e: map(lambda s: f(e,s), symbol),expiration)
```